# codigo de PHP dentro del foreach de AJAX (template)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, formularios, foreach

Necesito imprimir una plantilla (targeta con informacion en este caso) en el index.php, en tiempo real, con ajax. Pero estas targetas contienen un fragmento de codigo que corresponde a php, y al momento de ver los resultados, no imprime el codigo en php pero el resto si.

Aqui esta el codigo que esta escrito en un archivo javascript (app.js)

```
fetchx();
function fetchx(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'x.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            let x = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = '';
            x.forEach(x => {
                template+= ` 
    
                <div class="targeta" id="${x.id}">

                <div class="encabezado2">
                    <a href="${x.archivo}" target="_blank">
                        <h2 id="titulo">${x.titulo} </h2>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="recomendar-box">
                    <h1 class="recomendadot">Me sirvio</h1>

                <?php

                if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
                    $verificar = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $email WHERE id=".${x.id}."");
                }

                if(isset($verificar)):
                if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar) == 1): 

                ?>
                
                    <a class="unlike-btn" data-id="${x.id}"> <img class="unlike" src="unrecomendar.png"></a>

                    <a class="like-btn hide" data-id="${x.id}"> <img class="like" src="recomendar.png"></a>

                 <?php else:?>

                    <a  class="like-btn" data-id="${x.id}"> <img class="like" src="recomendar.png"></a>

                    <a class="unlike-btn hide" data-id="${x.id}"> <img class="unlike" src="unrecomendar.png"></a>

                    <?php endif ?>

                    <?php elseif(!isset($verificar)):

                        ?>
                    <a  onclick="redirigir(); "> <img class="like" src="recomendar.png"></a>
                    
                        <?php endif ?>

                </div>

            </div>
`
            });
            $('#targetas').html(template);
        }
    });
    
}
```

este codigo se imprime directamente en el div *targetas*, pero como bien nombre, el codigo php (ya sean funciones o condiciones) no efectua en este.

Comment: El código PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor la  _primera vez_ que se carga ese script. No se va a ejecutar cada vez que hagas la llamada por AJAX. Deberías tener esa lógica escrita en JS o bien en el archivo `x.php` y devolver directamente el HTML final.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la consulta de ajax para consultar el archivo php que tiene los valores que necesitas, devolves la data en un array asociativo desde php asi:

```
echo json_encode(["valor1"=>"este es un valor","valor2"=>"otro valor"]);
```

desde el archivo js lo recuperas en el reponse del ajax y lo parseas y usas los valores que pasaste desde el php asi:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(response);
alert(obj.valor1);
```

recorda siempre que el codigo php se ejecuta en el servidor y el js en el cliente, si necesitas traerte algo del php necesitas procesarlo asincronicamente con ajax, cualquier duda me preguntas.

Saludos